# What is the best way of replicating a database's schema in Powershell without using a backup?

Tags: sql-server, copy, powershell-7.0

I want write a PowerShell script that copies the structure of a database from a remote server to which I can read and write but I cannot back-up.  The database needs to be copied to a local installation of `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (Developer Edition)` from the remote server which is `MS SQL Server 2012 (Enterprise Edition)`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [dbtools.io](https://dbatools.io/) and exporting/importing dacpacs.

Related: [Using dacpac functions to clone sql server databases](https://dbatools.io/clone/)